# Why does the following mouse click code results in Windows error 997?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing a mini project where a switch press results in a mouse click or in other words the switch acts as an alternative to my left mouse button.

My code is

```
import pyautogui , time , serial

port = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
flag=0

while 1:
    reading=port.read()
    x=ord(reading)
    if x==1 and flag==0:
        flag=1
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
    elif x==2:
        flag=0
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

The serial transmission is such that it receives a

> 0 - Switch not pressed
>    1 - Switch pressed
>    2 - switch just left

A 2 is always transmitted in between a 1 and a 0.

My problem is that when I run this code the following error occurs after one mouse click.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\LeftClick.py", line 12, in 
>           pyautogui.mouseUp()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyautogui__init__.py", line
>   234, in mouseUp
>
> platformModule._mouseUp(x, y, 'left')
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_pyautogui_win.py",
>   line 415, in _mouseUp
>
> _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_pyautogui_win.py",
>   line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
>           raise ctypes.WinError()
>
> WindowsError: [Error 997] Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

Comment: I've just tried to replicate this (but without the serial stuff), and I can't. One suggestion though - can you use a different COM port for your switch? COM3 is historically the port used by the mouse - it could be causing some sort of a conflict. Or just take the serial out of the loop altogether and just see if you can generate the clicks in a for loop or using keyboard input to trigger.

Comment: If you press, hold and release the switch, what messages are sent?

Comment: @SiHa - COM3 works good for movement of mouse pointer and the program works without serial.

Comment: @caenyon only mouseDown()  is executed and then the above error occurs

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above, you say that if you take serial out, the program works as expected, if I read it correctly. You also say that mouse movement works OK on COM3, but if removing the serial comms fixes the issue, then I'd say that's a fairly strong indication that COM3 may be the culprit, it should certainly be investigated.

My suggestion: Use a different COM port for your serial device. You can change the number used by going into:

`Device Manager > Ports (COM & LPT) > Right Click your device > Properties > Port Settings > Advanced > COM Port Number`

Comment: I did the mouse click with ctypes module and it worked well.So the issue is definitely not in COM3.